# Проблемы со сменой фонового изображения сайта

Tags: javascript

Есть код, меняющий фоновое изображение веб-страницы. В режиме реального времени работает нормально, но когда надолго (от 3 мин и больше) происходит переход на другую вкладку в браузере Google Chrome и потом осуществляется возврат, бывает, что изображения сменяются один за одним без заданного интервала или вообще установлен фоновый цвет.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imgHead = [
            'images/photo-1485178575877-1a13bf489dfe.jpg',
            'images/photo-1512521743077-a42eeaaa963c.jpg',
            'images/dfgsdfgsdfg.JPG'
        ], i=1;
    function csaHead(){
        if(i > (imgHead.length-1)){
            $('.csa-head').animate({'opacity':'0'},500,function(){
                i=1;
                $('.csa-head').css({'background-image':'url('+imgHead[0]+')'});
            });
            $('.csa-head').animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
        }else{
            $('.csa-head').animate({'opacity':'0'},500,function(){
                $('.csa-head').css({'background-image':'url('+imgHead[i]+')'});
                i++;
            });
            $('.csa-head').animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
            
        }
         
    }
    var intervalCsaHead = setInterval(csaHead,6000);

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего браузер прекращает выполнение сценариев в неактивных вкладках для бытродействия. Попробуйте использовать css-анимацию

```css
.csa-head{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:#cda;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  animation: changeBackground 6s infinite steps(1),fadeToggle 2s infinite ease;
}
@keyframes changeBackground{
  0%{
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/be/Bliss_location%2C_Sonoma_Valley_in_2006.jpg/300px-Bliss_location%2C_Sonoma_Valley_in_2006.jpg);
  }
  33.33%{
    background-image: url(https://shop.doctorgavrilov.ru/395-large_default/tekhnika-avs-bezmyatezhnost.jpg);
  }
  66.66%{
    background-image: url(https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/8/1/4/5547418.jpg);
  }
}
@keyframes fadeToggle{
  0%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  50%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="csa-head">
  
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, так и сделаю

Comment: кстати на вашу ссылку браузер ругается

Comment: @Ilya , взял из поиска первые попавшиеся, думаю с вашими проблем не возникнет

Comment: прочитал, что для анимации не рекомендуется использовать нечисловые значения и фоновое изображение как-то слегка двигается вверх-вниз. Сижу думаю. А был ли у вас опыт использования в ключевых кадрах разных изображений?

Comment: был, вверху в сниппете. Слышал, что порядочные люди для этих целей готовые слайдеры используют

Comment: ну буду думать, спасибо за помощь